# K8s - Node alerts

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, alert

How can I configure GCP to send me alerts when nodes events (create / shutdown) happen?
I would like to receive email alerting me about the cluster scaling.

tks

Answer (score 2):

First, note that you can retrieve such events in [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) by using the following filter :

```
logName="projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" AND
(
    protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.create" OR
    protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.delete"
)
```

This filter will retrieve only audit activity log entries (`cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity`) in your project `[PROJECT_NAME]`, corresponding to a node creation event (`io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.create`) or deletion (`io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.delete`).

To be alerted when such a log is generated, there are multiple possibilities.

You could configure a [sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) to a Pub/Sub topic based on this filter, and then [trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) when a filtered log entry is created. This Cloud Function will define the logic to send you a mail. This is probably the solution I'd choose, since this use case [is described in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging).

Otherwise, you could define a [logs-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) based on this filter (or one logs-based metric for creation and another for deletion), and configure an [alert in Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) when this log-based metric is increased. This alert could be configured to send an email. However, I won't suggest you to implement this, because this is not a real "alert" (in the sense of "something went wrong"), but rather an information. You probably don't want to have incidents opened in Stackdriver Monitoring every time a node is created or deleted. But you can keep the idea of one/multiple logs-based metric and process it/them with a custom application.

Answer (score 0):

for a faster way than using GCP sinks, you may also consider using internal Kubernetes nodes watchers.

You can see an example in https://github.com/notify17/k8s-node-watcher-example/blob/5fc3f802de69f65866cc8f37c4b0e721835ea5b9/main.go#L83.

This example uses [Notify17](https://notify17.net/) to generate notifications directly to you browser or mobile phone.

The relevant code is:

```golang
// Sets up the nodes watcher
watcher, err := api.Nodes().Watch(listOptions)
// ...
ch := watcher.ResultChan()

for event := range ch {
    node, ok := event.Object.(*v1.Node)
    // ...

    switch event.Type {
    case watch.Added:
        // ... 
        // Triggers a Notify17 notification for the ADDED event
        notify17(httpClient, 
            "Node added", fmt.Sprintf("Node %s has been added", node.Name))
    case watch.Deleted:
        // ... 
        // Triggers a Notify17 notification for the DELETED event
        notify17(httpClient, 
            "Node deleted", fmt.Sprintf("Node %s has been deleted", node.Name))
    }
// ...
```

You can test out this approach by following the instructions provided in the [README](https://github.com/notify17/k8s-node-watcher-example/blob/master/README.md).

Note: the drawback with this method is that, if the node where the pod lies on gets deleted/killed unsafely, there may be a chance the event will not be triggered for that node. If the node is deleted gracefully instead, like in the case of a cluster autoscaler, then the pod will be probably recreated on a new node before the old node gets deleted, therefore triggering the notification.